# Good resources for advanced C++ topics?

Tags: c++, self-improvement

What are some good resources for advanced C++ topics. I know C++, but have little knowledge of threading, advanced meta-programming and inner-workings of meta-programming and I'd like to get better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A book I learned a lot from is "Advanced C++ Programming Styles and Idioms" by Jim Coplien. He starts very simple, then as you progress through the book the material becomes more and more challenging. At the end of the book you wonder whether this is still C++. Yes, it is!

This book certainly looks at C++ from a very specific angle. When I look at the various books I have read, this one sticks out and I learned a great deal from it. I'm sure other people have other favorites and that is fine, too. Jim's book is my favorite C++ book.